# Modificar cada dígito de una cadena por el siguiente (su sucesor)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

Tengo un archivo plano en formato UNIX delimitado por ; (Punto y coma) con la siguiente estructura:

```
2020-01-30;1010;1  
2020-01-30;1150;2  
2020-02-03;1190;3
```

Debo reemplazar cada caracter desde la posicion (12,4)

```
0->1  
1->2  
2->3    
3->4 etc etc...
```

Quedando:

```
2020-01-30;2121;1  
2020-01-30;2261;2  
2020-02-03;2201;3
```

He intentado con varias estrategias sin resultado positivo:

```
sed -i 's/0/9/g; s/1/8/g; s/2/7/g; s/3/6/g; s/4/5/g; s/5/4/g; s/6/3/g; s/7/2/g; s/8/1/g; s/9/0/g' data.dat > data1.dat
```

¿Tienen alguna estrategia?

Comment: ¿Por qué el 9 pasa a ser 0? ¿Siempre son 4 caracteres? ¿Entonces es tocar solamente el 2.º campo? Son detalles que sería bueno que aclararas

Comment: Hola @Fedorqui. Es valida tu apreciacion. 1. Si son siempre cuatro posiciones. 2. El 0->1, 1->2, 2->3, 3->4 ...... 8->9, 9->0. No es sumarle 1, es homologarlo para no desbordar el numero.

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser con `sed` obligatoriamente?

Comment: el problema con tu Sed es que necesitas valores temporales. Si tengo HOLA y quiero cambiar la O por la A y la A por la O, un primer cambio O por A enmascarará las A que queríamos cambiar por O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como no me dejaba dormir la idea de poder hacerlo con `sed`, al final propongo una respuesta para realizar lo mismo.

### Respuesta anterior

Con `awk` se puede hacer de una manera concisa:

```
#!/bin/bash

#   Declaramos que el            Declaramos que el
#   delimitador sea el ";"       separador de salida (OFS)
#          |                     sea ";" para ahorrarnos
#          |                     la escritura de caracteres.
#          |                      |
#          |                      |
awk --field-separator=";" -v OFS=";" '{ 
    split($2, campo2, "") # Creamos el array "campo2"
                          # cuyo contenido son las letras
                          # del segundo campo.
    $2 = "" # Borramos el contenido del segundo campo
    for ( numero in campo2 )
        $2 = sprintf( "%s%s",
                        $2,
                        (campo2[numero] + 1) % 10 )
    print $0 # O simplemente print, porque por defecto
             # imprime a $0   
}' numeros.txt
```

Lo que hago con `sprintf` es concatenar lo que tiene `$2` con el módulo 10 del número mas 1. De esa forma me aseguro que se quede en el conjunto del {0...9}.

Definir el `OFS` como `;` es para que al final, cuando hago `print $0`, ya no tenga que separarlo por `;` y `awk` lo haga por mi. `$0` tiene toda la información del registro, pero como modificamos la variable `$2`, entonces la información del registro se mantiene intacta salvo el segundo campo `$2`.

El resultado es el que deseas:

```
2020-01-30;2121;1
2020-01-30;2261;2
2020-02-03;2201;3
```

Sin los comentarios el código queda:

```
awk --field-separator=";" -v OFS=";" '{ 
    split($2, campo2, "")
    $2 = ""
    for ( numero in campo2 )
        $2 = sprintf( "%s%s", $2, (campo2[numero] + 1) % 10 )
    print
}' archivo.txt
```

### Actualización

Recientemente tomé un curso intensivo de `sed` de la Universidad del Internet y de la Universidad de Leer el Manual. Y logré obtener lo mismo pero con el mero uso de `sed`.

Antes de poner el código con la explicación incluida, creo que es necesario aclarar ciertos conceptos fundamentales:

- pattern space, es un buffer temporal de sed que recibe todos los caracteres y donde se hacen las modificaciones. **Sólo se puede interactuar con lo que hay aquí**
- hold space, es otro buffer temporal pero que puede almacenar ciertas cosas del *pattern space*. **No se puede interactuar directamente con este buffer; sólo a través de mandar cosas de un buffer a otro**. Lo que se encuentra dentro del hold space, se retiene entre ciclos: no cambia a menos que se le indique.

Para comunicar entre estos buffers se tienen los comandos `h,H,g,G,x`. Que copian o añaden desde el hold space al pattern space, o viceverss, o sólo intercambian lo que hay en uno por lo que hay en otro.

Esto lo explicaría como si fuese el libro *Molloy* de Samuel Beckett, donde el vagabundo trata de chupar cada piedra que tiene, ayudándose únicamente de los bolsillos (buffers), de sus sacos.

Una vez diciendo esto, pongo el código que deberá ser guardado en un archivo como `sed_file.sed` con permisos de ejecución dados por `chmod u+x sed_file.sed`:

```
#!/bin/sed -rnf
# -r, para utilizar expresiones regulares extendidas
# -n, para no imprimir el pattern space por defecto
# -f, para indicar que este archivo sea tomado como un script de sed

h  # Copiamos lo que se encuentra en pattern space al hold space

s/([^;]*?;)([[:digit:]]{4})(;.*$)/\2/  #  Lo que se encuentra en el pattern space le dejamos,
                                       #+ únicamente los cuatro números en el segundo campo,
                                       #+ dejándo únicamente lo de la forma 1002, 2032, etc.

y/0123456789/1234567890/;  #  Ya teniendo sólo esos cuatro dígitos en el pattern space,
                           #+ transliteramos número por su sucesor. Es decir, hacemos
                           #+ un desplazamiento en uno: el 0 al 1, el 2 al 3, etc.
#|                     |
#|_____________________|
#           |
#           |_____ ¡Esto sigue estando en el pattern space!
#                  Es decir, tenemos (únicamente) números como "2121"
#                  que provienen de otros como "1010".

G  #  Al pattern space se le añade un salto de línea, seguido de lo que está
   #+ el hold space (la cadena inicial que guardamos con el comando "h").

# Hasta aquí tenemos en el pattern space algo de la forma: 
#
#    <numerosaumentados>\n<la cadena inicial>
#
# Donde la cadena inicial es de la forma:
#    <fecha>;<numeros anteriores>;<un dígito>
#
#  Ahora tenemos que operar de tal manera que llevemos los números aumentados
#+ de la parte inicial, a en medio de <fecha> y <un dígito>

s/([[:digit:]]{4})\n([^;]*?;)([[:digit:]]{4})(;.*)/\2\1\4/
# |______________|  |_______||______________||___| |_____|
#         |             |            |         |      |
#         |             |            |         |      |__ Modificamos la salida de la
#         |             |            |         |          forma <fecha><numeros aumentados><un digito>
#         |             |            |         |
#         |             |            |         |__ Atrapamos el dígito en \4
#         |             |            |
#         |             |            |__ Atrapamos los números anteriores en \3
#         |             |
#         |             |
#         |             |__ Atrapamos la fecha en \2
#         |               
#         |__ Atrapamos los números aumentados en \1
# Todo esto sucede en el pattern space.

p  # Imprimimos el pattern space
```

O, sin comentarios:

```
#!/bin/sed -rnf
h
s/([^;]*?;)([[:digit:]]{4})(;.*$)/\2/
y/0123456789/1234567890/
G
s/([[:digit:]]{4})\n([^;]*?;)([[:digit:]]{4})(;.*)/\2\1\4/
p
```

Entonces corremos:

```
$ ./sed_file.sed numeros.txt
2020-01-30;2121;1
2020-01-30;2261;2
2020-02-03;2201;3
```

Answer (score 1):

La [respuesta de Cuauhtli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/350384/83) está muy bien y resuelve el problema correctamente.

Simplemente como referencia y para utilizar otras potencialidades de GNU Awk, veamos cómo hacerlo de otra manera:

```
gawk -F '' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%s", (i>=12 && i<=15) ? ($i+1)%10: $i; print $NF}'
```

En GNU Awk es posible definir el separador de campos como la "nada". Con ello, cada carácter es un campo diferente. Esto [se hace indicando `-F ''`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31135446/1983854).

De esta manera por ejemplo podemos decir:

```
$ awk -F '' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' <<< "hola"
h
o
l
a
```

Una vez aprendido esto, ahora es simplemente cuestión de iterar sobre la cadena y modificar los caracteres que hay en la posición 12 a 15, utilizando la lógica de la respuesta de Cuauhtli:

```
for(i=1;i<NF;i++) 
   printf "%s", (i>=12 && i<=15) ? ($i+1)%10: $i
print $NF
```

Es decir, itera sobre todos los caracteres e imprime el carácter en sí (`$i`) a menos que esté en la posición 12 a 15, en cuyo caso imprimimos `($i+1)%10`. Esta decisión la tomamos mediante el operador ternario `condición ? reacción_si_cierto : reacción_si_falso`.

Finalmente ponemos `print $NF` para escribir el último campo y que vaya seguido de un salto de línea, porque `printf` no los añade automáticamente y `print` sí.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con Perl, que viene por defecto en cualquier distribución linux.

```
 cat fichero.txt | perl -pne 's/(?:^[^;]+;\K|\G)\d/($&+1)%10/ge';
```

Al utilizar las opciones `n`, `e`, lo que hay a continuación se ejecuta para cada línea de entrada y se asume que está en un bucle, donde la variable por defecto (`$_`) obtendrá cada línea. Con la opción `p` se imprime al terminar cada iteración (el contenido de la variable)

Así pues como script lo que realmente hacemos es modiciar el contenido de esta variable, que tiene la línea.

Primero, vamos a "buscar" todos los números que hay en la segunda columna. Pero los iremos capturando de uno en uno, en lugar del bloque completo. Para cada captura, remplazaremos su valor por el "incrementado"

**Explicación expresión regular:**

(Usaremos el modificador "g" para hacer una búsqueda global)

```
(?: # Una de estas dos opciones:
      # opción1: Empieza el string, 
      #          seguido de uno o más caracteres que no sean ';'
      #          luego un punto y coma ';'
      #          y finalmente "olvidamos" lo capturado hasta ahora con \K
      ^ [^;]+ ; \K
      # opción2: Posición dónde nos quedamos justo después de la última búsqueda
    | \G
)
# Un número, es realmente lo que 'encontramos'. Lo anterior sólo es
# para saber a partir de dónde empezar a buscar.
# El valor estará accesible en $&
\d
```

Para ver esta expresión regular en acción (sin los remplazos) puedes ir a esta [demo](https://regex101.com/r/w8EUVo/2/).

Finalmente miramos con qué remplazarla.

```
($&+1)%10
```

En Perl, el modificador `e` en una expresión regular (como en `s/blabla/codigo/e`), permite **e**valuar código.

Como tenemos el número encontrado en `$&`, lo que hacemos es sumarle 1 y aplicarle un módulo 10 para de esta manera pasar a 0 cuando tenemos un 10.